# Is it undefined behaviour to access two objects of type T declared next to each other using T[]?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I recently watched a CppCon talk by Miro Kenjp on "Non-conforming C++: the Secrets the Committee Is Hiding From You".

At 28:30 (https://youtu.be/IAdLwUXRUvg?t=1710) He states that accessing doubles next to each other was UB and I don't quite understand why. Can someone explain why is this the case?

And if this is the case then surely its UB to access other things this way for example:

```c
int* twoInts = malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);
int secondInt = twoInts[1]; //Undefined behaviour?
```

Comment: `int secondInt = twoInts[1]` is UB, but for a slightly different reason then in the video (I think it might not be in C++20 though).  It is UB because `malloc` doesn't actually create anything, it just allocates memory.  Technically you are accessing a non-existing object, and that is UB.

Comment: @NathanOliver So in my example if I did `twoInts[1] = 10` before the access it should be defined behaviour? And could you expand on what the reason was in the video?

Comment: No, that would still be undefined behavior.  What you would need to make the above code legal is to add `int * good_two_ints = new(twoInts) int[2]{};` and then use `good_two_ints` going forward instead of `twoInts`.  This uses placement new to actually create an array object in the memory `malloc` acquired.

Comment: @NathanOliver So the use of malloc to create an array in this case is UB? Isn't this used a lot in C though? I know C and C++ are different languages but I thought C++ was compatible with C so this would be fine.

Comment: @NathanOliver Is placement-new of dynamically sized array safe? I was under the impression that it was unsafe because even placement-new makes no promises about overhead. AFAIK that `malloc` is technically UB is (was? I thought C++20 did something about it...) considered a defect in the standard.

Comment: *I thought C++ was compatible with C so this would be fine.* it is in some places, but more and more the languages are too distinct to really be compatible anymore.  Do yourself a favor and don't use C code in C++ until you've really mastered C++ and understand where C code can be valid.

Comment: @HTNW Oh dang, I forgot about that.  Yeah, ignore my suggested fix in my second comment.

Comment: @NathanOliver Array placement new is currently defective because it requires the provided pointer to point to storage that is larger than the storage required by the elements, but that extra overhead is unspecified and not portably knowable. You need to placement-new each element individually. However, it becomes unclear whether or not pointer arithmetic remains valid as the elements aren't technically part of an array of those elements.

Comment: @NathanOliver In the malloc case I just find it hard to see why it is UB because too my knowledge `twoInts[1]` is the same as `*(twoInts + 1)` which should point to the next int value as long as it has been written to. I dont understand *why* it is UB.

Comment: @NathanOliver I believe since C++20 it is no longer required to placement new trivially constructible types, it introduces the term [vacuous lifetime](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.life#def:initialization,vacuous).

Comment: @name The linked video is dated 2019, so we can assume it is referring to at most C++17. In that version, `twoInts` does not point to an array of `int`. It points to storage that would be large enough to accommodate two `int`. You needed to somehow create `int`s in those storage locations before you could actually use them. `malloc` doesn't work like `new` in C++. It only creates storage, not objects.

Comment: @name It is illegal pre C++20 because of [this paragraph](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/intro.object#1), particualrly, the text *An object is created by a definition, by a new-expression, when implicitly changing the active member of a union, or when a temporary object is created ([conv.rval], [class.temporary]).*.  `malloc` is not mentioned there, so `malloc` does not create objects.  If you don't have an object, then there is nothing there for you to work with and any work you do, is UB.

Comment: @user4581301 While you aren't wrong (on the count of examining generated machine instructions), this is a similar strategy to burying a landmine in your front lawn, but claiming it's okay because you know where you buried it and know not to walk there. Even if you put up a sign (document it) the slightest inattention, from you or the next person to walk by, could be disastrous.

Comment: I'm not going to argue with that. I'm going to replace the "or" with "and" though, since you need all three to have a good chance of success and add a caveat.

Comment: @NathanOliver So if I where to loop over my `twoInts` and use placement new then would that be fine? for example `int* firstInt = new (twoInts) int(10);` and `int* secondInt = new (twoInts + 1) int(10);` such that the objects are created. Or does this also suffer from the overhead issue @HTNW mentioned.

Comment: You may have UB that you know--through years of experience, rigorous experimentation, and careful examination of the produced machine instructions--will result in exactly the behaviour you need for your target platform and with a given compiler. When you have exhausted the other reasonable options, you carefully employ UB.

Comment: @name Yeah, that doesn't work either because then you just have two `int`s next to each other in memory.  They aren't an array and using the memory like an array violates the pointer addition rules.

Comment: @NathanOliver Pointer addition rules? Sorry I'm quite new to this stuff haha.

Comment: When you do `arr[1]`, it is actually `*(arr + 1)`.  So you are adding `1` to the pointer, and then dereferencing that location.  The rules about pointer addition say that you are only allowed to do this in the range of array, and since you don't have an array, the behavior is UB.

Comment: Two variables defined next to each other are probably next to each other in memory, but what if the compiler sees an advantage in inserting a little padding between the two? Maybe it sees a chance to optimize cache lines.

Comment: @user4581301 Out of curiosity is this only the case in C++ because if not, then surely C has this problem as well when you use malloc to dynamically allocate an array?

Comment: Different languages, man. C++ has much, much stricter rules. A lot of this stems from butt-covering over the construction and destruction of complicated classes, `malloc`ing a `std::string` for example is a big mistake.  In C you can have complex structures, but you do not have any hard requirements that they have to be correctly initialized at a given point in time, just that they are before use. C++'s rules are lightening up on simple structures over time as the language describing C++ in the Standard becomes more precise.

Comment: No, C doesn't have this problem. It used to in 1989, but they changed the standard language in 1999 to make it defined. It took C++ another 20 years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I want to start with a quote from the presentation:

> You are not programming against the CPU, you are programming against the abstract machine

You say:

> He states that accessing doubles next to each other was UB

But your quote is incomplete. He specifies this very crucial fact:

> ... unless the objects are part of an array

`malloc` is a red herring (and a bag of another set of problems). His code uses `new[]` so `malloc` is just poisoning the well here.

The specific problem he mentions on his slides is that the `double` objects created on the `buffer` are created by [`std::uninitialized_default_construct_n`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/uninitialized_default_construct_n) and this method doesn't create an array of doubles, but instead creates multiple objects that are consecutive in memory. He asserts that in the C++ standard (the abstract machine you are programming against) you can't treat objects as part of an array unless you actually created the array of objects.

The point the author tries to make is that the C++ standard is flawed and there is no strictly conforming way to create a flexible array (pre C++20).

---

For reference here is the code (reproduced after image):

```
struct header
{
    int size;
    byte* buffer;
    thing some;
};
```

```
constexpr size_t x = ...;

byte* buffer = new byte[x + n * sizeof(double)];
header* p = new (buffer) header{n, buffer};
uninitialized_default_construct_n(
    reinterpret_cast<double*>(buffer + x), n);
double* data = reinterpret_cast<double*>(p->buffer + x);

data[0] = data[1] + data[2]; // <-- problem here
                             // because we never created an array of doubles
```

Comment: I see, this basically covers most of my thoughts, just is there a specific reason as to why you can't treat objects as part of an array unless you actually created the array of objects. I thought that an array is just objects that are consecutive in memory.

Comment: @name because the standard says so. Why? It's a way longer and complicated discussion.

Comment: is there a source I can read up on as to why?

Comment: @name Usually such alising rules are helpful for compiler optimization. With such rules, the compiler can infer that an object cannot be accessed through other unrelated objects.

Answer (score 2):

There is no guarantee that the variables will be allocated next to each other.

1. The memory area used by `malloc` may be a different region than the memory area for temporary, local, variables.
2. Local variables may not be stored in memory.  They could be stored in registers.
3. Accessing array elements outside the declared range is undefined behavior.
   The array could be allocated at the end of memory, so accessing outside the array has no memory assigned to it.
4. Local variables may be defined in another memory segment, e.g. stack., that is not the same as memory for dynamic allocation.

Here's an example.
An embedded system has On-Chip Memory and memory outside the "System on the Chip" (SOC).  The On-Chip memory is faster, but there is less of it.  The architects assign this memory to the stack.  The memory outside the SOC is slower, but there is more of it, so it is assigned to the dynamic memory.

Another example:
The operating system supports virtual memory.  Memory is paged onto the hard drive as needed.  The operating system assigns a small amount of memory to your program.  The small amount of memory will be assigned to the stack and the virtual memory will be assigned to dynamic memory.

Not all platforms are made of contiguous memory.  Memory locations may also be assigned to hardware devices.

Comment: But in the case I described (not sure about the case described in the video) the memory accessed is what has been given by `malloc` which should mean that it is contiguous?

Comment: Yes, but that's not what I'm referring to.  Many developers believe that a computer has a range of addresses and all that range is memory (and contiguous).   In fact, there may be some ranges of address that have nothing assigned or related to them.